# Custom Post Query Combined with Conditional Tags

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, conditional-tags

Is it possible to combine displaying a list of custom post types on a single page depending on conditional tags?

Below is what I have so far, basically if there are 4 posts or less show the posts, if there are more than 4 posts show another list.

Currently it just shows the first list, though.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'cases','posts_per_page' => '-1') ); ?>

<?php if ($wp_query->found_posts <= 4) { ?>

    <!--4 and less posts -->
    <ul class="case-list clearfix">

        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <li id="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></li>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>

    </ul>

<?php } else { ?>

    <!--4 and above posts -->
    <ul class="case-thumbs clearfix">

        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <li id="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></li>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>

    </ul>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Well, your `WP_Query` is stored in `$loop`, and yet you check `$wp_query`...?

Comment: Oh, and the loops (and thus the posts) are exactly the same, BTW. I did not check that before because of the `$wp_query`. So **what** list do you want to show if there are more than 4 posts? You did not set up the according query, right?

Comment: I get the impression assumptions were made by the asker that require the answerers to posess psychic powers. Sadly my crystal ball is out of service today and clarification is necessary. I suggest you write out what you want in pseudocode, and be ***precise/specific***. There's a lack of detail here, and it's causing confusion

Comment: My mistake the stored $loop needed to go in the found_posts. Thank you for your help.. stupid mistake.